# How to set automatic width?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I would like to use something like "dock" for `ListView` columns. I would like to set a minimal width for column 1 and 2, but I want them to expand to match the whole `ListView` width, which has `Dock` set to `Fill`.

Is it possible? It would be great to be also able to set column width as a percent value of it's length. I was searching the Web and many people say to set width to -2, but it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two basic options:

- You can pick one of the `ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle` options: `ColumnContent`, `HeaderSize` or `None`. The options do what their names suggest. Note that they are only applied when you set them. This means that to make `HeaderSize` you have to **first** add the columns, **then** set the option. And to make `ColumnContent` work you need to **first** add the columns **and** also fill the items with their content!
- Or you can chose to script the `Resize` event to size the columns to your liking. I append code that resizes each column so that the `ListView` is filled and each column keeps its old percentage of width.

With a little extra coding you will also be able to mix the options:

- Instead of using `AutoResizeColumns` to set the same option for all columns you can also use `AutoResizeColumn` which sets the option for one single column.
- If you want a column to not participate in the percentual Resizing you can simply mark it in some way; for a simple implementation I chose to mark a fixed column by setting its `Tag = "#"`

Here is the code for setting all columns to the same option:

```
listView1.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.ColumnContent);
listView1.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.HeaderSize);
listView1.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.None);
```

And here is a resize code that makes all columns keep their relative widths while still filling the ListView:

```
private void listView1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  int oldsum = 0;
  foreach (ColumnHeader ch in listView1.Columns) oldsum += ch.Width;

  foreach (ColumnHeader ch in listView1.Columns)
  {
    if (ch.Tag != "#") ch.Width = ch.Width * listView1.ClientSize.Width / oldsum;
  }
}
```